# Maven release plugin fails for cross module dependencies

Tags: maven, dependency-management, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi module maven project, like this:

```
parent
    moduleA
    moduleB
    moduleC
```

All the modules inherit their version from the parent pom. moduleC has a dependency to moduleB, so the pom.xml for moduleC contains:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>blah</groupId>
    <artifactId>moduleB</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

This is all fine. I can run the install goal without any problem, and the dependencies resolve fine.

However, I'm trying to do a release using the maven release plugin using the following command:

```
mvn release:prepare -DreleaseVersion=1.0 -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I can see that all the versions in my pom are updated correctly. However, the problem arises when it tries to compile the code. Because release:prepare does not call the install goal, the compilation for moduleC fails because it cannot resolve the dependency to moduleB version 1.0.

Has anybody else come across this problem? I think having cross module dependencies is fine, but the maven release plugin doesn't seem to cater for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: First can you show the full error message apart from that have you tried to build your project with a clean local repository from scratch with `mvn clean package`?

Comment: With a clean local repository, `mvn clean package` fails because moduleC cannot resolve the dependency to moduleB because it has not yet been installed to the local repository. However `mvn clean install` works because moduleB gets installed to the local repository and by the time moduleC builds, it can resolve the dependency to moduleB. (I won't bother with the full error message - it is simply the standard error from maven when it can't resolve a dependency from the central and local repository.)

Comment: If it is as you mentioned your project does not correctly define the dependencies between modules. Can you show the full pom's of this project? May be on GitHub or so? Have you given the correct classifier/type (module B)?

Comment: Thanks khmarbaise for asking the right questions. moduleB has a packaging type of "bundle" (maven-bundle-plugin). This is causing the problem. If the packaging type is "jar" then the dependencies resolve fine.